# How to encourage users, visually, to associate a Knowledge Base article with a Case?

Tags: case, knowledge, articles

Our customer wants to encourage users to link Cases to Knowledge Base articles, preferably by some kind of warning/visual cue. Not all Cases must be linked to an article, but most can and should be. The Service Console already suggests appropriate articles, but it does not (and it should not) force the user to pick one or more articles.

There does not seem to be a master-detail relation between Case and CaseArticle, so I cannot use a roll-up summary field to determine whether 0, 1 or more articles have been linked to a Case.

I was thinking about a custom field in the Case object, which signals whether an article is linked or not. And to have this custom field updated by a workflow or a trigger. Some formula could then display a graphic, depending on the value of the custom field.

Turns out: it is not possible to create a workflow or a process or a trigger on a CaseArticle object.

Anybody recognize this problem? Did you solve it?

It is possible to create a report that shows Cases without linked articles, and to correct any problems later on, but it is more efficient to deal with this earlier on in the process.

Comment: The customer is going to settle, for the time being, with a permanent text or picture on the top of the screen, containing a reminder about adding articles to Cases. Implemented via a formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much deliberating, this is what we implemented: a custom button Close, which replaces the standard button Close. The custom button calls Javascript, which in its turn calls an Apex method that determines whether or not an Article has been linked to the Case. It not, it shows a Javascript alert.
Either way, the user is redirected to the Close Case window, but the user will have been notified of a missing Article. If (s)he wants to link the Case to an Article, the Close action can be canceled.